# "Раненый" или "раненный"?

Tags: орфография

Меня заклинило: сколько Н в слове "ранен(н)ый"? И, главное, каким правилом это регламентируется?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

РАНЕ**Н**ЫЙ — образованно от глагола и пишется с одним Н: ране**н**ый зверь. А РАНЕ**НН**ЫЙ — это причастие, с НН: ране**нн**ый (где?) в бою солдат, ране**нн**ый (куда?) в руку, то есть, присутствует зависимое слово. Если Вам этого объяснения мало, то вот как это правило трактует портал Грамота.ру:

*Если есть зависимые слова, то верно написание с двумя Н: раненный в ногу солдат. Если нет — с одним: раненый солдат. Также бывают случаи, когда разграничение причастий (с двумя Н) и прилагательных (с одним) производится по смысловому значению. Например: Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю — слово раненным пишется с двумя Н, так как сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние.*

Comment: Неудачная формулировка у Грамоты, на мой взгляд. Количество "н" зависит **только** от части речи, а наличие зависимых слов — это формальный признак, облегчающий определение части речи.

Comment: Я согласен, в "грамотной" формулировке признак и причина перепутаны. Но это настолько общая ситуация, что спорить уже не приходится. Понимаете, когда детям забивают голову многочисленными орфограммами, первопричина в их сознании исчезает, говорить о стройности логики уже не приходится.