# "будучи" + краткое причастие

Tags: грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Есть ли какое-то ограничение для использования деепричастия "будучи" и краткого прилагательного в одном словосочетании? Например: *"Будучи ранен, он был направлен в госпиталь"* или *"Будучи снисходителен и терпим, он не стал возражать".*

То же самое интересно в случае деепричастия "являясь".

Спасибо.

UPD. Прощу прощения за неточность. "Ранен", разумеется, есть краткое причастие. Отсюда расширяю свой вопрос до следующего: "Есть ли какое-то ограничение для использования деепричастия "будучи" и краткого прилагательного/краткого причастия в одном словосочетании?".

Comment: "Ранен" -  краткое страдательное причастие. Но конструкция с "будучи ранен" верна.

Comment: С этим я не спорю.

Comment: А уточните-ка вопрос, а то тут Серж с Galina Avanesova уже запутались . )))

Comment: Ну поскольку Вы без комментариев приняли ответ Галины, считаю свой вопрос излишним. ))) А жаль. Вопрос-то мне показался интересным.

Comment: Так а что мешает продолжить дискуссию?) Основной вопрос получил ответ, по крайней мере я для себя решила, что использовать конструкции типа "будучи спокоен и нежен..." (и "будучи ранен", что проиллюстрировано примерами в ответе Галины:) ) нигде не возбраняется (с "являясь" не особо понятно, хотя, но чисто по наитию - "являясь спокоен и нежен" как-то уродливо звучит). А остальные вопросы, в частности о разграничении причастий и прилагательных, появились по пути.

Comment: Так то и мешает, что, если ответ принят в процессе дискуссии, то ответ автор счел достаточным. Я-то грешным делом думал, что они куда-то забрели в туман, возможно потеряв нить, возможно изначально неправильно поняв вопрос. Но, коли ответ принят, это исключено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С деепричастием *будучи* нет противопоказаний в соседстве краткого прилагательного; иное дело с *являясь*...

*Являясь* и *будучи* синонимичны при сочетании с существительным (являясь/будучи профессиональным программистом... являясь/будучи классиком русской литературы...) или субстантивированным прилагательным (являясь/будучи служащим), с другими частями речи *являясь* как-то хило контактирует, я не нашла примеров.

Зато с *будучи* - стопиццот, квантум сатис (в переводе Петрушевской - до омерзения):

> ***Будучи молод*** и ***вспыльчив***, я негодовал на низость и малодушие смотрителя, когда сей последний отдавал приготовленную мне
>   тройку под коляску чиновного барина, -

ничтоже сумняся, повествует Солнце Русской Поэзии.

Конкретно по шапке вопроса:

нет никаких ограничений на употребление кратких прилагательных с деепричастием *будучи*.

И оба Ваши примера совершенно, как сказала бы Грамота.ру, коррэктны.

> К весне Мизогин перепробовал всех шляпниц и, ранее ***будучи неприхотлив***
>   в отправлении естественных потребностей, пришел в восторг.

---

Дополнение по мотивам комментариев:

> [***Будучи ранен***](http://www.vladoblprof.ru/obkom-zdravoohraneniya-rf/3496-2015-02-27-13-44-31), он продолжал вести огонь и ушёл в госпиталь только
>   по окончании боя (осколочное ранение в плечо и ногу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(Это из Гугл-Книги, то есть с корректурой и редактурой.)

> Продолжая вести разведку, Братухин натолкнулся на группу противника
>   численностью 30 человек и вступил в неравный бой. ***Будучи ранен,***
>   он с сержантом доставил в штаб 5 пленных немцев с документами, после
>   чего был направлен в госпиталь.

ПРОСТО заголовок статьи:

[«**БУДУЧИ РАНЕН,** ПРОДОЛЖАЛ УНИЧТОЖАТЬ ФАШИСТОВ…»](http://m.noar.ru/news/detail/70let/Pobeda70-Buduchi-ranen-prodolzhal-unichtozhat-fashistov/)

Comment: Галина, однако Розенталь с вами несогласен по по поводу "Будучи ранен".

Comment: Розенталь учит различать отглагольное прилагательное и причастие; это просто о другом речь. То,  что у Розенталя пример именно с "будучи раненным" - случайное совпадение.

Comment: Galina, я знаю, что речь о другом. Но вы говорите, что ''"Будучи ранен'' правильный пример. Но ведь "ранен'' не краткое прилагательное, а краткое страдательное причастие. Здесь деепричастие ''будучи'' вносит временной признак, усиливая глагольность, поэтому "раненный".  А ''ранен" краткое страдательное причастие.

Comment: Я набрала стопиццот примеров употребления "будучи ранен", дополню ими свой ответ...

Comment: ну да, будучи ранен - страдательное причастие.

Comment: В суффиксах полных страдательных причастий пишется две буквы Н, например, СПИЛЕННЫЕ ДЕРЕВЬЯ. В суффиксах кратких страдательных причастий пишется одна буква Н, например, ДЕРЕВЬЯ СПИЛЕНЫ. - http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_106 Вот об этом у Розенталя.

Comment: Галина, я знаю это правило. :).

Comment: Но вот вопрос: а в чем разница: будучи раненным и будучи ранен? Вы видите разницу?

Comment: Разница такая: язык стремится к лаконизму. К "экономии средств". )))

Comment: Не думаю, но постараюсь узнать.

Comment: Спасибо вам, Галина, и всем комментирующим за разъяснения.

Comment: А-а-а! Тут не так благодарят! Нужно всем (если всем - спасибо) кликнуть по верхнему треугольничку слева от ответа, а самому-самому вразумительному и непадеццки помогшему - зажечь зеленым звёздочку (внизу слева), чтоб было ответчику ЩАСТЕ! )))

Comment: Я бы рада, да вот только рейтинга это сделать мне пока не хватает :)

Comment: Ли, обратите внимание, что тут о языковых проблемах, с осуждением некошерных ответчиков и минусованием оных, выступают такие особи, которые собственноручно рисуют "но причем тут деепричастие?.."  Это уже дисквалификация, профнепригодность и полные кранты.

Comment: Уау! Да там что ни слово, то... лес густой: "Там есть о чем поговорить но причем тут деепричастие "являясь"? Там любое деепричастие будет по мнению авторов неверным, если запретить использование деепричастий в пасивных конструкциях". (Взято подряд. А пройтись по комментам и ответам - ваще! круто непадеццки!) Апарте: ошибки в комментах можно исправить в течение пяти минут, в ответах - неограниченно. Пусть незамутнённая цитата сохранится у меня, туточки.

Comment: Galina, а причем тут профнепригодность? Я не профессионал, смне не стыдно и ошибаться. Нот вот Вы с вашим воинствующим невежеством и снобизмом никак на человека знающего не тянете.

Comment: *Я бы рада, да вот только рейтинга это сделать мне пока не хватает :)* - Это дело поправимое. Вы можете "принять" лучший ответ, а карму поднять очень легко. Но сразу скажу, выпрашивать себе репутацию от новичков, подобно тому, как это  делают некоторые озабоченные недавноприбывшие граждане, граждане здесь не принято. За это я буду минусить.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: И оба Ваши примера совершенно, как сказала бы Грамота.ру, коррэктны._ ===

Не надо опускать Грамоту.ру до своего уровня!

Answer (score 1):

Очень много разговоров, все не по существу.

"Будучи" сейчас считается принадлежностью скорее книжного и архаичного стиля. Но это стилистическая особенность, грамматика не ограничивает, да и сама это "книжная" классификация спорна.

В отношении "являясь" вообще не могу представить, почему к нему такое отношение. Грамматических причин избегать его нет, стилистика тем более не ограничивает. Единственное, что можно сказать в этом плане: "являться" - глагол многозначный, возможно с эти связаны рекомендации избегать его использование в значениях синонимичных "быть". Возможно это перенеслось и на деепричастие.

Все раговоры вокруг неверного использования деепричастия (Серж и Galina Avanesova) строятся на подмене понятия. Там не использование деепричастия ошибка, а неверная (якобы) конструкция с деепричастным оборотом, перепевы на тему "подъезжая к сией станции... с меня слетела шляпа". Там есть о чем поговорить, но при чем тут деепричастие "являясь"? Там **любое** деепричастие будет по мнению авторов неверным, если запретить использование деепричастий в пасивных конструкциях.

Хотя это не предмет обсуждения, я скажу, что не считаю *грамматической* ошибкой предложения типа "выходя из магазина, он был остановлен охраной", "разбирая рукописи, он был поражен обилием материала" и т. д. формально действующее лицо тут одно и в деепричастном обороте, и в главном члене. То, что в данном случае сказуемое выражено пассивом ничего не значит. 
Поэтому и в "Будучи ранен, он был направлен в госпиталь" ошибки не вижу. Но тут можно спорить, согласен, не все такой линии придерживаются. Но это не проблема исключительно деепричастия "будучи"

"Ранен" может быть и прилагательным и причастием, надо смотреть по контексту. Хотя в сочетании с "будучи" причастие вернее. Но грань эта настолько тонкая, что заострять я бы не стал.

Вот пример из нацкорпуса.

М. И. Богданович. Восточная война 1853-1856 годов. Т. 1 (1876)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)

> Генерал Фрейтаг, впереди своих егерей, *будучи ранен пулею в руку и контужен в живот, был принужден выехать из огня* для перевязки, но как только ему отрезали мизинец правой руки, возвратился снова в дело. [М. И. Богданович. Восточная война 1853-1856 годов. Т. 1 (1876)]

(Курсив мой, b-s).

Тоже, скажете, неправильно?

//-----------------

Серж заставил меня еще раз крепко задуматься об иллюзорности отличий причастий и глагольных прилагательных.  Ведь по сути дела ничего кроме лишней головоломки школьникам это систематика не дает. Все, ради чего она используется  - незначительные отличия в орфографии (одно/два Н в кратких формах для мужского женского рода и невозможность слитного написания "не"). Во всех остальных случаях обе части речи занимают одно и то же место в грамматике, смысловые различия весьма условны...

В свое время меня на эту мысль навел Аваенсов, фактически поставивший под сомнение последний бастион апологетов разделения этих двух частей речи - неспособность прилагательного заменять причастие в причастном обороте.

Но это, наверное, не здесь и не сейчас...

А сейчас я просто думаю, что если можно сказать про человека, что он ранен не по состоянию временному, а постоянно (с войны, допустим), то почему это причастие?!

Вот история 
этого раненного:

["Раненый" или "раненный"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21595)

Comment: Я рада, что мой вопрос вызвал такое интересное обсуждение. Хоть ваш ответ и не отвечает на изначально поставленный вопрос, мне стало интересно, почему конструкции вида "деепричастный оборот+пассив" комментаторы ниже забраковали, а вы - нет. Может опять-таки найдется ссылка на какой-нибудь более-менее авторитетный источник, подтверждающий одну/обе позиции?

Comment: Действие, которое выражает деепричастие, должно относится только к подлежащему. Именно поэтому в страдательных конструкциях не допускается использование деепричастного оборота. Т.к. в пассивных конструкциях подлежащее указывает не на реальный субъект, а на объект действия (который обычно выражается творительном падежом).Об этом Вы можете прочитать в любом учебнике по русскому языку.

Comment: *Хоть ваш ответ и не отвечает на изначально поставленный вопрос,* - Отчего же? Мне кажется он единственный из всех и отвечает . Правильно или нет - это обсуждаемо. Но это ответ по сути, во всяком случае я старался и стараюсь отвечать именно на вопрос, а не на мысли случайные. Как вы ставите вопрос - и чем мой ответ не подошел под эту постановку? Иногда, согласен, бывает непросто понять, что именно спрашивают, но разобраться всегда можно и полезно.

Comment: *мне стало интересно, почему конструкции вида "деепричастный оборот+пассив" комментаторы ниже забраковали, а вы - нет.* - это у авторов забраковавших надо спрашивать источник. Вы у меня вроде как разрешительный документ спрашиваете, а по мне так все, что не запрещено, все разрешено, это общий принцип. Но общие рассуждения могу показать. Пассивные конструкции сказуемого в русском языке вообще вещь спорная. Есть они или нет - непонятно, сильно зависит от систематики.

Comment: Так вот, когда говорят о том, что действие деепричастия должно относиться к том уже объекту, что и действие сказуемого,  часто путают две вещи. Есть агенс, активно действующая субстанция или субъект, и есть подлежащие. Это не одно и тоже. Так вот вопрос в том, является ли то, что тут назвали пассивом, действующим субъектом? Это не агенс в чистом виде, но это подлежащее. Я считаю, что да, в подобных конструкциях подлежащее действует, т.е. принятие действие на себя есть (в русском) частный случай действия. Это общий принцип теоретической грамматики.

Comment: *Действие, которое выражает деепричастие, должно относится только к подлежащему* - Серж, простите, Вы мне надоели .окончательно. Ваши формулировки "найти в любом учебнике" просто неприличны. Вы или не сами учебников не читаете, или не понимаете того что прочли. Вам надо - вы и ищите.

Comment: Да, Paprikash Li, если что-то не ясно, всегда отвечу по существу. Если действительно непонятно, я настаивал на той мысли, что деепричастие "будучи" никак не выделяется из всех других деепричастий в плане грамматики деепричастного оборота. Поэтому поставленный вопрос о "будучи + причастие " слишком узок. Ничего принципиально отличного от вообще "деепричастие+причастие" вы тут не найдете. Поэтому я и отвечал в свете понимания более общего случая - о грамматики деепричастного оборота вообще. И тут принципиально разошелся с Сержем и Галиной, которые за деревьями примеров леса грамматики не видят.

Comment: Знаете, вы себя считаете самым умным здесь. Тот ошибся, этот неправильно ответил. Пишете какую-то отсебятину, ставите под сомнение учебники, всех критикуете. Я вам не предлагал ничего искать и читать. Не умеете читать - не читайте и не оскорбляйте других.

Comment: Минус мой.  Ранен - причастие. Найдите пример, источник, доказательство, где "ранен" будет кратким прилагательным. Все у вас спорное, невнятные формулировки, не основанные ни на чем, как на собственном мнении.

Comment: Что значит "я считаю так''? А вот я не считаю так!

Comment: Сержик, а зачем вообще вступать в переговоры с конкретным неучем? Помните, Аглая надиктовывает: "Я в торги не вступаю"? Это болезнь - менторствовать в той области знаний, по которой не получено никакого образования. Термины из высшей школы и - немыслимая орфография...

Comment: Галина, это уже не первый случай.

Comment: Галина, дожен вам сказать, что я не вступаю в пререкания только с хамами. А насчет неучей - это вы зря. Не вам такие выводы делать.

Comment: *А вот я не считаю так!* - понятия не имею, что вы хотите этим сказать. Во всяком случае, мне ваше мнение ни о чем не слишком интересно.

Comment: *Ранен - причастие. Найдите пример, источник, доказательство, где "ранен" будет кратким прилагательным.* Серж, уже не смешно. Раненый - прилагательное. Нигде не сказано, что у него нет к4гораткой формы. Так что источник искать вам.  Где будет сказано, что ранен - не может быть прилагательным. И ещё. Не хотел этот вопрос снова ставит, у Вас русский - родной? Понимаете, для человека исповедующего методики РКИ и гичего больше не признающего, ваше стремление перейти на личности и ставит вопрос "сделайте мне красиво" понятно. Но мы здесь не этим занимаемся. **Вам** искать я ничего не обязан. DIXI.

Comment: Раз уж вы говорите о прилагательном, то уж будьте добры, привести пример. Теоретически, конечно, у прилагательного раненный может быть и краткая форма. Но важна не теория, а наглядный пример, где "ранен" будет кратким прилагательным. А если не можете обосновать - то и писать нечего.

Comment: Серж, я не понимаю эту логику, на что Вам примеры приводить? Вы с логикой не согласны? Покажите цитату, где было бы сказано, что  ранен *не может* быть прилагательным - и почему, в отличие от всех прочих прилагательных?  И почему недостаточно уже существующих? Я Вам цитату привел из донесения, там "ранен" и "контужен" - прилагательные. Вы вообще как отличаете одно от другого? Если только потому, что не нашли подходящей строчки в учебнике, то примеры бесполезны.

Comment: *А если не можете обосновать - то и писать нечего* - а вот это не Вам решать. Я тоже думаю, что Ваша аргументация никакой критики не выдерживает.

Answer (score 0):

Оба деепричастия употребляют не с *краткими*, а с *полными* прилагательными.

*Будучи ранен**ым**, он был направлен в госпиталь* (Как правильно отметил Hermit, фраза не очень корректна, стоит заменить на "в качестве раненого").
*Будучи снисходительн**ым** и терпим**ым**, он не стал возражать.*

Comment: Спасибо большое. Есть ли ссылка на какой-нибудь справочник/словарь?

Comment: Не за что) Надо поискать.

Comment: *Будучи раненым, он был направлен в госпиталь.* == Это ошибочная конструкция с деепричастием. Надо вот так: *"Будучи голодным, он зашёл в шикарный портовый ресторан"*. Сам голодный и сам зашедший.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, пассив тут не очень подходит.

Comment: Не нашёл ничего подходящего, к сожалению.

Comment: *Оба деепричастия употребляют не с краткими, а с полными прилагательными.*  - источник?

Comment: Мне так казалось, возможно, я и ошибался...

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном вами примере "ранен" не краткое прилагательное, а краткое причастие. Деепричастие в этом примере соотносится с глаголом, а не с прилагательным. Вот правило:

Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выяснение вопроса о написании нн – н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению. Например, в предложении ***Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю слово раненным пишется с двумя н,*** несмотря на отсутствие при нем приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием, а не прилагательным; отглагольные прилагательные действия не обозначают и отвечают на вопросы: **к а к о й? к а к а я? к а к о е? к а к и е?**

См.: [Справочник по русскому языку. Розенталь. Д.Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62)