# Читаем Розенталя: будучи раненным или будучи раненым?

Tags: грамматика, причастия, нн, прилагательными

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

"В предложении «***Будучи раненным***, солдат оставался в строю»  в слове «раненным» пишется НН, несмотря на отсутствие приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием".

**Но может ли деепричастие «будучи» управлять причастием в полной форме?**

Рассмотрим примеры:

*Солдат ранен – солдат был ранен* (причастие в краткой форме).

*Солдат раненый – солдат был раненый* (прилагательное в полной форме).

Как тогда правильно: **будучи раненым или будучи раненным?** Разве  можно использовать причастие в полной форме в таком обороте?

В Нацкорпусе можно встретить три варианта:  ***будучи раненным, будучи раненым, будучи ранен***.
Мне кажется, что правильно так: будучи раненым или будучи ранен.  В некоторых случаях значение действия не кажется очевидным, и тогда можно использовать полную форму прилагательного.

В примере у Розенталя лучше обойтись без деепричастия, например: ***Раненный***, солдат всё-таки  оставался в строю до конца боя (уступительное значение: хотя был ранен, это причастие).

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

(1) *Этого колосса разрывной пулей не свалишь, а **раненный**, он рассвирепеет, и нам придется плохо*. [В. А. Обручев. Земля Санникова (1924)]

*При этом все оборонявшиеся были погребены под ее руинами, за исключением одного из этих русских офицеров, который, **будучи раненным** и не желая сдаваться врагу, застрелился.* [ Русские в Бандерах // «Солдат удачи», 2003.03.12]

...*в «Прорыве» том выразительно написано, как солдат бился до конца, не уходил с поля боя **будучи раненым** и «заражал своим примером…* [Виктор Астафьев. Пастух и пастушка. Современная пастораль (1967-1989)]

*Димитрий, **не будучи раненым**, все это время пролежал под «срубленным деревом»*? [Н. И. Костомаров. Русская история в жизнеописаниях ее главнейших деятелей. (1862-1875)]

*И известный наш писатель Борис Васильев повел речь о том, как он в войну, **будучи ранен**, лежал в госпитале в городе Костроме.* [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

*В 1941-м участвовал в первых же боях с немцами и, **будучи ранен**, попал в плен.* [Е. М. Мелетинский. Моя тюрьма (1971-1975)]

**Примечание.** На форуме обсуждалась подобная тема, но там говорилось о краткой форме причастия ***ранен***.  Меня же интересует правомерность употребления причастия в полной форме ***раненный*** в этом обороте. ["будучи" + краткое причастие](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420651/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

**ПОМОГИТЕ, ЗНАТОКИ! ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!**

Почему вы не отвечаете? Давайте я по-другому вопрос задам.

Какой ответ верен: 1) только ***будучи раненным***, 2) только ***будучи раненым,*** 3) допускаются **оба варианта** (надо проверять качество или действие).

Это же классика орфографии! И при этом  реально существует разное написание, надо же понять, как правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Русская корпусная грамматика описывает общий случай:

> Семантически деепричастие остается в рамках глагола: оно сохраняет
>   значение действия (и другие глагольные значения), характерное для
>   исходного глагола управление в словосочетании и некоторые глагольные
>   категории.

Лопатин:

> 3. Причастия не на *-ованный* (*-ёванный*, *-еванный*) глаголов несовершенного
>      вида (они образуются только от бесприставочных глаголов) и
>      соотносительные с ними прилагательные пишутся по-разному: причастия с
>      *нн*, прилагательные — с одним *н* <...>
>
> По этому правилу пишутся формы двувидовых глаголов контузить, крестить
>   и ранить. Ср.: контуженный в голову боец, тяжело раненный солдат,
>   раненный в ногу солдат, только что крещённый младенец, но: контуженый
>   командир, раненый солдат, крещёный ребёнок.
>
> **Примечание**. Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию
>   зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово
>   не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики
>   явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при
>   прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской
>   (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Можно сделать такой вывод: 
если глагол *быть* допускает после себя и страдательное причастие, и прилагательное (быть увлечённым / быть белым), то без зависимых слов можно использовать любой вариант от глагола *ранить*, и это уже вопрос стиля, а не орфографии. 
По Розенталю, *ране**нн**ый* подчеркнёт временность состояния, *ране**н**ый*, видимо, его постоянность.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. 1) «Увлеченный» может быть причастием или прилагательным. Разве можно сказать: лодка была увлеченная течением. Мы говорим: лодка была увлечена течением.  Если между деепричастием и глаголом есть соответствие, то мы должны писать: будучи увлечена течением. 2) Как я поняла, вы допускаете две формы (будучи раненым и будучи раненным), но в правилах Розенталя указана только форма причастия, а она вызывает сомнение. Кроме того, в соответствии с правилом пользователи будут использовать только эту форму, а «будучи раненым» считать ошибочной. Это нормально?

Comment: И еще просьба: вы можете привести два примера с оборотом "будучи раненным/раненым", где значение качества и действия четко различаются.

Comment: 1) Можно выбрать другое. 2) А у Лопатина прилагательное. 3) Розенталь обозначил, что раздел идёт по смыслу. В его примере боец только что был ранен, но строя не покинул. Обратите внимание на "иногда" в статье. Смысл зависит от цели автора.

Comment: Не могу. Я особой разницы между двумя формами не вижу. Разве что нечто вида "Будучи раненым, боец лежал в госпитале с другими больными". То есть когда "раненый" стало сущ., как "больной".

Comment: Кажется, что здесь такая же грань, как в правиле про "не" и подразумеваемое противопоставление: формальных признаков нет, всё зависит от смысла. Может быть нечто "Будучи раненным [легко/недавно/в руку], боец оставался в строю".

Comment: Ваши примеры мне кажутся верными, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу никаких оснований сомневаться в формулировке Розенталя. Ваши же сомнения отношу на счет не совсем удачной интерпретации. Поэтому ограничусь разбором ключевого положения.

> Но может ли деепричастие «будучи» управлять причастием в полной форме?

Без проблем. Только причастие это, как и положено по грамматике, должно ставиться в творительном падеже, что, собственно, и представлено у Р. Поэтому ваши примеры с лодкой, которая "будучи увлеченная", как аргумент не годятся.

> Будучи рожденным в глухой провинции, в Пьяченце, в доме из темного
>   кирпича, доставшегося семье по наследству, среди добропорядочных
>   соседей и разговоров об урожае и вине, он, попав в Милан, старался ―
>   по его собственным словам ― выглядеть по-милански более, чем сами
>   миланцы. [Яна Зубцова. Мании по Армани // «Домовой», 2002.04.04]
>
> Будучи лишенным костылей, человек представляет из себя крайне слабое,
>   теплолюбивое, избирательное в пище, постоянно болеющее и с большим
>   трудом и неохотой размножающееся создание. [Андрей Макаревич. «Сам
>   овца». Автобиографическая проза (2000-2001)]

Примеры из Нацкорпуса, их таких много, смущает, правда, то, что все они современные... Но с другой стороны, краткая форма тут явно не подходит, она придавала бы существенно другой смысл.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. 1) Он был рожденным (рожденный) в глухой провинции. Как-то не очень звучит. Вероятно, у формы будучи есть особые привилегии, и Т.п. воспринимается на слух как норма для сущ., прилаг,. причастий. 2) Но брошенный и рожденный - это однозначно причастия, а Розенталь решает проблему различения прилагательного раненый и причастия раненный. Получается, что оборот с будучи - это не лучший вариант для их различения. 3) Как я поняла, Вы придерживаетесь мнения, что однозначна верна форма "будучи раненным" и написание с одной Н будет ошибкой.

Comment: *Получается, что оборот с будучи - это не лучший вариант для их различения* - Я уже сказал, что вы, имхо, своеобразно трактуете Розенталь не предлагает эту форму как инструмент для дифференциации прилагательного и причастия. Р. просто дает пример случая, когда выбор диктует внутренняя семантика конструкции, а не формальные признаки.

Comment: *ак я поняла, Вы придерживаетесь мнения, что однозначна верна форма "будучи раненным"* - отнюдь. Возможны оба варианта, выбор диктуется семантикой, более того, подозреваю, что иногда только авторское понимание может диктовать такой выбор  - в абсолютно тождественном общем контексте.

Answer (score 1):

**Большое спасибо участникам,** которые ответили на вопрос и помогли мне разобраться в теме. Сейчас я представляю ситуацию примерно так.

1) Оборот с ***будучи*** является **универсальной конструкцией** и может управлять Т.п. **всех частей речи** (причастия, прилагательного, существительного), также он сочетается с краткими формами.

2) У Розенталя приведен **правильный пример с причастием** (*будучи раненным)*, но пользователи, скорее всего, считают это **единственным решением**, что не совсем верно, поэтому вопросы могут возникать.

3) С другой стороны,  сама тема **различения причастий и прилагательных** довольно сложна, а в этой конструкции особенно.

Поэтому форму причастия ***будучи раненным*** можно считать **общим упрощенным решением,** но  не следует видеть ошибку в тех примерах из художественной литературы, где ***будучи раненым*** использовано **на законных основаниях** (то есть имеет качественное значение прилагательного).

А это **мои примеры**:

***Будучи раненным***, солдат продолжал сражаться и не покинул поле боя.

Это значение завершенного действия, причем это **действие относится ко времени**, которое описывается в данном предложении.

Оборот имеет обстоятельственное уступительное значение, и его выражает причастие.

***Будучи раненым***, он был эвакуирован в тыл и так и не вернулся в свой полк.

Здесь определительное значение (*раненый* – это человек, получивший ранение, которому требуется лечение). Это результат действия, но это **действие  не относится ко времени**, которое описывается в данном предложении.

Оборот имеет  обстоятельственное значение причины, но  его выражает прилагательное.