# прилагательное или причастие

Tags: орфография

Как писать "смертельно раненый" - с одним или двумя "н"? Вроде бы имеется зависимое слово, как "раненный в бою", но по смыслу как будто прилагательное, как "раненых отправляли в госпиталь".

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21595/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Answer (score 0):

1) **В Нацкорпусе встречаются оба варианта**, на вариант "смертельно раненый" обычно относится к старым текстам (до 1956 года), когда орфография еще не имела единого свода с чёткими правилами.

В то же время и  в настоящее время можно встретить вариант с одной буквой Н, что может быть связано с разным пониманием семантики этого словосочетания: получивший смертельную рану (причастие) или ещё некоторое время живущий со смертельной раной (прилагательное).

2) **В современной орфографии** это скорее причастие с двумя буквами НН: смертельно раненный боец.

3) Надо особо отметить,  что речь идет о тех случаях, когда мы имеем **необособленное определение без других зависимых слов**.  При обособлении даже одиночное слово пишется  с двумя НН (нет перехода в прилагательное): В сорок первом году, когда сам он, **раненный**, попал в плен и гнали их под конвоем, увидел он с холма всю колонну. [Г. Я. Бакланов. Навеки девятнадцатилетние (1979)]

**Примеры**

Кричал **смертельно раненный** мальчик, что волок корзину по снегу. [Ю. В. Трифонов. Нетерпение (1973)]

Но **смертельно раненный** конь его рухнул вместе со всадником. [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга вторая. Ч. 3 (1939-1945)]

Он слышал, как крикнул **смертельно раненный** казак Первушин, слышал осторожные голоса немцев впереди и слева и лежал, затаив дыхание. [В. А. Закруткин. Пятый патрон (1946)]